# How to connect boxplot median values

Tags: python, pandas, plot, line, boxplot

It seems like plotting a line connecting the mean values of box plots would be a simple thing to do, but I couldn't figure out how to do this plot in pandas.

I'm using this syntax to do the boxplot so that it automatically generate the box plot for Y vs. X device without having to do external manipulation of the data frame:

```
df.boxplot(column='Y_Data', by="Category", showfliers=True, showmeans=True)
```

[image]

One way I thought of doing is to just do a line plot by getting the mean values from the boxplot, but I'm not sure how to extract that information from the plot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can save the axis object that gets returned from `df.boxplot()`, and plot the means as a line plot using that same axis.  I'd suggest using Seaborn's [`pointplot`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.pointplot.html#seaborn.pointplot) for the lines, as it handles a categorical x-axis nicely.

First let's generate some sample data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

N = 150
values = np.random.random(size=N)
groups = np.random.choice(['A','B','C'], size=N)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':values, 'group':groups})

print(df.head())
  group     value
0     A  0.816847
1     A  0.468465
2     C  0.871975
3     B  0.933708
4     A  0.480170
              ...
```

Next, make the boxplot and save the axis object:

```
ax = df.boxplot(column='value', by='group', showfliers=True, 
                positions=range(df.group.unique().shape[0]))
```

Note: There's a curious `positions` argument in Pyplot/Pandas `boxplot()`, which can cause off-by-one errors.  See more in [this discussion](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6630#issuecomment-37642249), including the workaround I've employed here.

Finally, use `groupby` to get category means, and then connect mean values with a line plot overlaid on top of the boxplot:

```
sns.pointplot(x='group', y='value', data=df.groupby('group', as_index=False).mean(), ax=ax)
```

[image: boxplot]

Your title mentions "median" but you talk about category means in your post.  I used means here; change the `groupby` aggregation to `median()` if you want to plot medians instead.

Comment: An excellent answer!  I haven't used Seaborn package but looks like it's a logical choice to have to do this and I already have all the dependencies.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value of the medians by using the `.get_data()` property of the `matplotlib.lines.Line2D` objects that draw them, without having to use seaborn.

Let `bp` be your boxplot created as `bp=plt.boxplot(data)`. Then, `bp` is a `dict` containing the `medians` key, among others. That key contains a `list` of `matplotlib.lines.Line2D`, from which you can extract the (x,y) position as follows:

```
bp=plt.boxplot(data)
X=[]
Y=[]
for m in bp['medians']:
    [[x0, x1],[y0,y1]] = m.get_data()
    X.append(np.mean((x0,x1)))
    Y.append(np.mean((y0,y1)))
plt.plot(X,Y,c='C1')
```

For an arbitrary dataset (`data`), this script generates [this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmbpX.png). Hope it helps!